# Check if custom Attribute has value true

Tags: java, liferay, velocity, liferay-velocity

I followed [**this guide**](http://blogs.xtivia.com/home/-/blogs/19104) to create a *Custom field* in Liferay. 
I have created a true/false attribute, but i want to check if this attribute is true or false, if is true get to the menu/Page a cssClass.
I tried with this:

```
#set ($menu = $nav_item.getLayout().getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("get-menu"))
#if ($menu == "true")
    <a href="" class="menu True">$nav_child.getName()</a>
#else
    <a href="" class="menu">$nav_child.getName()</a>
#end
```

But doesn't work!
How can i check if Custom Attribute has value true or false?
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **get-menu** custom field for Page is declared as boolean above if condition should work

```
#if ($menu)
#if ($menu == true)
```

If it still does not work Check Database for **ExpandoColumn** table it will have your column name  **get-menu** and default value if set.

**ExpandoValue** table will have actual value for your custom field, look for **columnId** that correspond your custom field and **classPK** which will be your page layout ID. This row will have your Value i.e. Either true / False.

If this row is present for your Page it should work in your VM code above.

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 1):

If that is a boolean value, you can use any of:

```
#if ($menu)
#if ($menu == true)
#if ("$!menu" == 'true')
```

However, it should work with your code as well, so maybe you're reading the value wrong. What is the value of `$menu`? Just print it to find out.